# Flutter Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

*W/DynamiteModule( 6380): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6380): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerin
staller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6380): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local
version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/Firestore( 6380): (24.4.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/firstName order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=
PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter ( 6380): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have p
ermission to execute the specified operation.
E/flutter ( 6380): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter ( 6380): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:296:18)
E/flutter ( 6380): 
E/flutter ( 6380): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:499:43)
E/flutter ( 6380): 
E/flutter ( 6380): #3      MethodChannelDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_refe
rence.dart:69:42)
E/flutter ( 6380): 
E/flutter ( 6380): #4      _JsonDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:146:7)
E/flutter ( 6380): 
E/flutter ( 6380): #5      ProductList.build. (package:firebasekurulum/basket.dart:16:28)
E/flutter ( 6380): 
E/flutter ( 6380):
W/Firestore( 6380): (24.4.0) [WatchStream]: (f4f9d06) Stream closed with status: Status{code=CANCELLED, description=Disconnecting idle stream. Timed out
waiting for new targets., cause=null}.
*

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'basket.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // This is the theme of your application.
          //
          // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
          // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
          // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
          // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
          // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
          // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
          // is not restarted.
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: ProductList()
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {
  final fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference datas = fireStore.collection('users');
    var ref = datas.doc('firstName');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
        child: Text("press"),
        onPressed: () async {
          var response = await ref.get();
          print("here is your data :  $response['firsName']");
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this message and others too. Following advice, I quit AndroidStudio and then started it up again, and those messages didn't return ... Other error messages showed up, but those errors are based on my code : )

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error message and resolved it by updating my firestore rules properly.
To test it you can set your rule to :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But beware as this rule will allow anyone to write in your database. My suggestion is to test if your app runs properly after this change and then change it to a proper rule.